# "Dispatcher has no subscribers" during startup

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am currently facing a problem which only happens sometimes and is very hard to reproduce. Therefore I have problems actually creating a compelling test case.

Our setup looks like this:

- spring integration with spring boot
- rabbitmq listener
- custom bus which manages transaction aware messages

The setup is not the newest anymore and probably a lot of code could be replaced by more idiomatic spring wiring.

Though this is the exception I am getting when the service is started:

```
 Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=com.foobar.service.greencheckout.message.GreenOrderPropertyAddedMessage@2ba0efb2, headers={id=f750a792-6b01-16d3-8206-6e553a03f8fa, type=com.foobar.service.greencheckout.message.GreenOrderPropertyAddedMessage, amqp_deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, timestamp=1505797680967}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=com.foobar.service.greencheckout.message.GreenOrderPropertyAddedMessage@2ba0efb2, headers={id=f750a792-6b01-16d3-8206-6e553a03f8fa, type=com.foobar.service.greencheckout.message.GreenOrderPropertyAddedMessage, amqp_deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, timestamp=1505797680967}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:135)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:392)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:477)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:429)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:420)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy223.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.foobar.library.messaging.bus.TransactionAwareBus.afterCommit(TransactionAwareBus.java:50)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:133)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:121)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:958)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:803)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.foobar.service.greencheckout.silo.domain.modifyingservice.TransitionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$de36730c.execute(<generated>)
    at com.foobar.service.greencheckout.silo.domain.statemachine.OrderFsm.invokeCreationalCommandMethod(OrderFsm.java:380)
    at com.foobar.service.greencheckout.silo.domain.statemachine.OrderFsm.lambda$allowCreational$1(OrderFsm.java:345)
    at akka.japi.pf.FSMStateFunctionBuilder$2.apply(FSMStateFunctionBuilder.java:80)
    at akka.japi.pf.FSMStateFunctionBuilder$2.apply(FSMStateFunctionBuilder.java:77)
    at akka.japi.pf.CaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:18)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.CaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:13)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.CaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:13)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.CaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:13)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.CaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:13)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at akka.actor.FSM$class.processEvent(FSM.scala:663)
    at akka.actor.AbstractFSM.processEvent(AbstractFSM.scala:36)
    at akka.actor.FSM$class.akka$actor$FSM$$processMsg(FSM.scala:657)
    at akka.actor.FSM$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(FSM.scala:651)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:497)
    at akka.actor.AbstractFSM.aroundReceive(AbstractFSM.scala:36)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=com.foobar.service.greencheckout.message.GreenOrderPropertyAddedMessage@2ba0efb2, headers={id=f750a792-6b01-16d3-8206-6e553a03f8fa, type=com.foobar.service.greencheckout.message.GreenOrderPropertyAddedMessage, amqp_deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, timestamp=1505797680967}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:154)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    ... 58 more
```

The code to set this up looks like:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Exchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint;
import org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.ExecutorChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.NullChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer;
import org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

@Configuration
public class MessagingOutboundConfiguration
{
    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Exchange publisherExchange;

    @Autowired
    private AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin;

    @Autowired
    private Exchange errorExchange;

    @Autowired
    private Queue errorQueue;

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ExpressionParser expressionParser;

    @Autowired
    private MessagingSettings messagingSettings;

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"connectionFactory", "consumer"})
    public AsynchronousBus asyncBus(SubscribableChannel amqpOutboundChannel) throws Exception
    {
        GatewayProxyFactoryBean factoryBean = new GatewayProxyFactoryBean(AsynchronousBus.class);
        factoryBean.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        factoryBean.setDefaultRequestChannel(amqpOutboundChannel);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (AsynchronousBus) factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public TransactionAwareBus transactionAwareBus()
    {
        return new TransactionAwareBus();
    }

    /**
     * Channel from message bus to the outbound channel adapter
     */
    @Bean
    public SubscribableChannel amqpOutboundChannel(HeaderChannelInterceptor headerChannelInterceptor)
    {
        DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
        channel.setComponentName("amqp-outbound-channel");
        channel.addInterceptor(headerChannelInterceptor);
        return channel;
    }

    /**
     * Outbound Channel Adapter
     */
    @Bean
    public AmqpOutboundEndpoint endpoint(SubscribableChannel confirmationChannel)
    {
        DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper headerMapper = DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.outboundMapper();
        String[] allowedHeaders = new String[]{"*"};
        headerMapper.setRequestHeaderNames(allowedHeaders);
        headerMapper.setReplyHeaderNames(allowedHeaders);

        AmqpOutboundEndpoint endpoint = new PhasedAmqpOutboundEndpoint(amqpTemplate);
        endpoint.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper);
        endpoint.setExchangeName(publisherExchange.getName());
        endpoint.setRoutingKeyExpression(expressionParser.parseExpression("headers.type"));
        endpoint.setConfirmCorrelationExpression(expressionParser.parseExpression("#this"));

        if (messagingSettings.getPublisherConfirmations()) {
            endpoint.setConfirmNackChannel(confirmationChannel);
            endpoint.setConfirmAckChannel(new NullChannel());
        }

        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public HeaderChannelInterceptor headerChannelInterceptor()
    {
        return new HeaderChannelInterceptor();
    }

    /**
     * Shovels messages from channel to outbound channel adapter
     */
    @Bean
    public EventDrivenConsumer consumer(SubscribableChannel amqpOutboundChannel, AmqpOutboundEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        final EventDrivenConsumer consumer = new EventDrivenConsumer(amqpOutboundChannel, endpoint);
        consumer.setBeanName("amqp-outbound-consumer");

        return consumer;
    }

    /**
     * Outbound Channel Adapter
     */
    @Bean
    public AmqpOutboundEndpoint errorEndpoint()
    {
        amqpAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(errorQueue).to(errorExchange).with("#").noargs());

        DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper headerMapper = DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.outboundMapper();
        String[] allowedHeaders = new String[1];
        allowedHeaders[0] = "*";
        headerMapper.setRequestHeaderNames(allowedHeaders);

        AmqpOutboundEndpoint endpoint = new PhasedAmqpOutboundEndpoint(amqpTemplate);
        endpoint.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper);
        endpoint.setExchangeName(errorExchange.getName());
        endpoint.setRoutingKeyExpression(expressionParser.parseExpression("headers.routing"));
        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public EventDrivenConsumer errorConsumer(SubscribableChannel errorChannel, AmqpOutboundEndpoint errorEndpoint)
    {
        final EventDrivenConsumer consumer = new EventDrivenConsumer(errorChannel, errorEndpoint);
        consumer.setBeanName("amqp-error-consumer");

        return consumer;
    }

    @Bean
    public SubscribableChannel errorChannel()
    {
        DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
        channel.setComponentName("amqp-error-channel");
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    public SubscribableChannel confirmationChannel()
    {
        ExecutorChannel channel = new ExecutorChannel(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
        channel.setComponentName("amqp-confirmation-channel");
        return channel;
    }

}
```

From my understanding:

This message normally means (especially in the shutdown case) that beans are not correctly wired or that the context does not know the best order for stopping them.

What I do not understand: What's wrong with my setup? :(

*UPDATE*:

As you can see the code is called from inside an actor. The actor system is configured this way:

```
@Bean
@DependsOn({"asyncBus", "prototypedTransactionAwareBus", "transactionAwareBus", "syncBus"})
public SpringActorSystem actorSystem() throws Exception
{
    String profile = environment.getActiveProfiles()[0];

    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create(akkaSettings.getSystemName(), akkaConfiguration(profile));

    if ("testing".equals(profile)) {
        Cluster.get(system).joinSeedNodes(Lists.newArrayList(Cluster.get(system).selfAddress()));
    }
    if ("kubernetes".equals(profile)) {
        joinKubernetesSeedNodes(system);
    }

    SpringExtension.SpringExtProvider.get(system).initialize(context);

    return new SpringActorSystem(system);
}
```

And the SpringActorSystem:

```
public class SpringActorSystem implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringActorSystem.class);

    private final ActorSystem actorSystem;

    public SpringActorSystem(ActorSystem actorSystem)
    {
        this.actorSystem = actorSystem;
    }

    public ActorSystem system()
    {
        return actorSystem;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event)
    {
        final Cluster cluster = Cluster.get(this.actorSystem);
        cluster.leave(cluster.selfAddress());

        LOGGER.info("SpringActorSystem shutdown initiated");

        this.actorSystem.terminate();
        try {
            Await.result(actorSystem.whenTerminated(), Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info("Exception while waiting for termination", e);
        }

        LOGGER.info("SpringActorSystem shutdown finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show more StackTrace. According to your config you have something performing `AsynchronousBus` and my best guess that it is done somehow asynchronously. Would be great to see that code as well.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I added more of the StackTrace. Hope this helps. The `AsynchronousBus` is the first Bean configured in the config.

Comment: Yes, that helps a bit, but you still have to show who uses `AsynchronousBus`. I see its definition and that's why I'm asking about its usage. Exactly this gateway performs send to the message channel too late. But it isn't guilty in the problem. According your stack trace the call comes from the `TransactionAwareBus`. Maybe you use there something like `@Async` or that `OrderFsm.lambda$allowCreational$1` is called async when application context is stopped already. So, more code into the studio!

Comment: @ArtemBilan I am so sorry! I added the complete stack trace. It was wrong from me to cut it to make it look shorter and therefore easier to read. Sorry. I also added the code for how the ActorSystem is setup.

Comment: Hm, the SpringActorSystem needs to implement the correct bean lifecycle, right? This simply is the wrong approach to wire Akka and Spring Lifecycle together?

Comment: I was aloy reading the logs incorrectly: this happens on startup and not on shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think

SpringExtension.SpringExtProvider.get(system).initialize(context);

in the initializing phase is really too early.

Consider to implement `SmartLifecycle` for your `SpringActorSystem` to mover that `initialize(context)` to the `start()` method.

Comment: Currently testing the solution and will come back if battleproof. Thank you very much!